# Can a KafkaReceiver be created without broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I'm creating a reactive consumer for Kafka messages using [reactor-kafka](https://projectreactor.io/) and I'm looking for a way to create unit tests.

For instance, in the following consumer, I would like to verify if the call to **commit** has been executed.

```
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;

class ReactiveEventConsumer {
    public ReactiveEventConsumer(KafkaReceiver<Integer, Object> kafkaReceiver) {
        kafkaReceiver
                .receive()
                .doOnNext(record -> System.out.println("Kafka message received " + record))
                .doOnNext(record -> record.receiverOffset().commit())
                .subscribe();
    }
}
```

I know I could setup an EmbeddedKafka and create the KafkaReceiver based on the broker properties. This is somewhat of an overhead, because I want my test to focus on the reactive-part and not on the kafka-part.

Can I create a KafkaReceiver without broker?

Or are there other ways to test this kind of setup?

Comment: You could mock the receiver

Comment: I could but then I would be mocking internals of reactor-kafka (and I have no control over how this evolves)